# Problema com @media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Estou com um problema serio com o Media Query, eu estou testando nesse codigo e não muda o estado de jeito nenhum, reduzo a tela ao maximo e as cores continuam sem mudar; HELP

```css
 .box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box2{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box3{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: pink;
}
@media screen (min-width:480px){
  .box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .box2{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .box3{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: grey;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Teste</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  <div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque esta linha `@media screen (min-width:480px){` por:

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px){
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/jjkr0xku/) no jsfiddle

Atenção que assim os estilos que estiverem definidos em dentro desse [media querie](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) são aplicados quando a janela for maior que 480px. Caso queira que eles aconteçam quando o tamanho da janela for inferior a 480px:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/jjkr0xku/1/) no jsfiddle

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, deu super certo.

Comment: De nada @FilipeTrader

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa declarar a viewport no head do html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Aí a partir disso, você pode definir as media queries no css normalmente.

E lembrando que é necessário colocar "and" depois de screen, como na resposta acima

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px)
```

[Mais sobre viewport na w3cSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: Muito obrigado meu bom, deu certo.